# remove duplicates but retain the first position in excel vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, retain

I am looking to remove duplicate rows but leave the first line
Using vba macros in excel 2010.

This is the initial information

```
   A | B  
1. A | 1  
2. A | 1
3. A | 1
4. A | 1
5. B | 2
6. B | 2
7. B | 2
```

after running the macro

```
   A | B
1. A | 1  
2.   | 1
3.   | 1
4.   | 1
5. B | 2
6.   | 2
7.   | 2
```

Can you help me,please!

Comment: Hi, you may want to see [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: You could use conditional formatting to make those entries invisible.

Comment: I have a solution for this, thank you for your interest :)

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but quick and dirty:

```
Dim iLastRow As Integer

iLastRow = 13
Range("h1:h" & iLastRow).Formula = "=if(countif(a$1:a1,a1)>1,"""",a1)"
Range("a1:a" & iLastRow).Value = Range("h1:h" & iLastRow).Value
Range("h1:h" & iLastRow).Clear
```